# NPM SOAP package - client as singleton?

Tags: node.js, soap, soap-client

I'm using this npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

I could not find an answer in the documentation, as I'm wondering if the best practice for SOAP client is to create a single client as startup and use for all requests (similar to database client), or create a new one per request.

Comment: Any progress about it?

Comment: @hurricane what exactly are u , asking?

Comment: @Webruster You can answer the current question.

Comment: @hurricane, I decided to use it as singleton.
Create one client at startup and that's it. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: @DavidFaiz Thank you for your answer. Can you show me your example?

Comment: @hurricane, I create the client like so
https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#soapcreateclientasyncurl-options---create-a-new-soap-client-from-a-wsdl-url-also-supports-a-local-filesystem-path

And save it in a variable of global scope. Then use it in a method that sends requests to the desired URL.

Comment: @hurricane what is your client side framework you are using ? are you using Angular4?

Comment: @hurricane, I write in node, all javascript, no Angular.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your use case and application requirements.

After reading up on the code of the `node-soap`, the following happens when `createClient()` is called:

- `createClient(url, options, cb)` internally creates a wsdl handler for the particular url in question (`wsdl.open_wsdl()`)
- the wsdl handler is cached with the `url` as key (unless `options.disableCache` is `true`)
- `createClient()` calls back with `Client()` which wraps the wsdl handler

So, unless your `url` changes, it should be ok for you to use it as a singleton, since there's no need to run the setup code for wsdl yet again.

If your `url` changes (or if you aren't sure if it changes), use `createClient()` for each call. The wsdl setup will still be cached, so there's no overhead for you in this case (except for the first time the wsdl is created).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the handler is cached without me needing to dig through the docs.  (I needed to know this because the contents of the wsdl file changed and was mystified as to why new calls to createClientAsync didn't seem to be respecting the new contents.)